# How to disable the JSP validation in Eclipse helios?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a Maven project set up in my **Eclipse Helios 3.6**. It builds and deploys perfectly fine. But it shows a red mark on my project and shows a lot of JSP issues. I want to somehow get rid of these JSP validation issues in problem view. One example of JSP issue is *ArrayList* can not be resolved to a type.
    What I have done for this is  inside **window->preferences->web->jsp files->validation** I have unchecked the validate  jsp fragments Apart from this I right clicked
    On my project. Go to **Properties->Validations** then checked suspend all validator check box **but stiil i see same issues in problem view and see red mark on my project?**

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I do similar as Aravind but I do it on the general settings: Preferences > Validation. Here I deselect all 'Build' checkboxes but leave the 'Manual' select for when I want to manually validate a JSP, XML, ... .

Comment: Actually made it worse for me

Answer (score 3):

@Stijn's answer works great, but it disables *all* validation for JSPs. Sometimes, that validation can be very useful to point out where you've got errors.

If you still want to have your *normal JSPs* validated, just *not your JSPFs* (JSP fragments), follow these steps:

1. Open `Window` > `Preferences` from the menu.
2. Navigate to `Web` > `JSP Files` > `Validation`.
3. Uncheck the "Validate JSP fragments" checkbox.

This is one of the first things I do with web projects that use JSPs in a new Eclipse installation. I've just confirmed in the JEE version of Eclipse Mars, but I'm pretty sure it'll work pretty much the same way in older versions as well, going back to around 3.2. Your JSPs should still get validated, but the validator should leave your JSPFs alone... obviously, your fragments must use the `.jspf` extension for this to work.

Comment: It's strange that the same aspect (JSP validation) shows in a different interface in two Preferences dialogs (Validation and Web/JSP/Validation).  This reminds me of another duplicate (Java build path/Projects and Project References).

Answer (score 2):

I usually do the following - Right click project - properties -Validation -->Configure settings link on validation frame - Disable all .Also Right click project - properties -Validation --> JSP Syntax - Uncheck project specific settings .

Comment: Thats what i also did suspend all validators. May be these errors are previous to these settings. Is there any way i can delete all errors in from problem view in one go as i have 7390 errors?

Comment: @MSach right click in your problems view , select all -- > press delete button .

Comment: I have 22000 errors in jsp. It aonly allows me to select maximum 100  in one go. In that way i have to do it 220 times. Is there a way i can do it in one go?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using sts-2.5.0.RELEASE (based on Eclipse 3.6) and I solved the problem unchecking these properties:

Preferences > Validation > JSP Content Validator (uncheck manual & build)

Preferences > Validation > JSP Syntax Validator (uncheck manual & build)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of disabling your validations, which is a good aspect in eclipse.

Just select the whole code cut and paste it back on the same page, All the reds will vanish automatically.
If the reds are still present, that means there is some problem in the code which you are writing.

Validations generally help you alot in eclipse, the jsp's can sometimes be an issue regarding these validations.

Comment: I've always done this to force-refresh the validation when I'm editing JSP. But sometimes the validator can still give you errors or warnings that shouldn't be there at all. JSP validation in Eclipse is useful, I agree, but it's also quite buggy unlike Java validation which works smooth as a breeze (if it gets crazy I just need to hit Ctrl-S).

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the JSP file > Properties
Select the "Derived" checkbox.