# java ee jspf taglib

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee

I put my base.jspf inside WEB-INF/jsp/ folder with following content :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

And I also define WEB-INF/web.xml with following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Address Book Application</display-name>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
            <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/base.jspf</include-prelude>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
            <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

But when I access the taglib in different jsp files, it always give me error that it doesn't understand either c or fn. I'm using Eclipse Luna as my IDE with Java SE 8. Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the jar with those tags? Exactly what error message are you getting?

Comment: It's with the pom.xml file and the error message is : "The function fn:length is undefined" on the other.jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same syntax-checking complaints using Eclipse Luna (and also in what seems to be the same situation, i.e. working through the examples of that excellent book by Nick Williams)... don't have a "you change the Eclipse settings thus"-answer, nor do I have a clever-clogs answer overall, but the workarounds I have used so far are these:

1a - Override your jsp-config of the Deployment Descriptor, by adding one line of code to any jsp files that are syntax-whinging:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/base.jspf" %>
```

This solves the issue. Only downside is if you object to adding one extra line of code to potentially lots of jsp files... though I am guessing you could define a New JSP Template with that include line, uhh, included :)

1b - Even more manual workaround: usually a quick glance at the syntax-complaints shows you what isn't yet imported or included into the offending jsp file - so you copy the relevant missing lines only from the base.jspf, in this case I am treating the jspf as a kind of template-store in itself. But for sure it's not a very elegant way of working on my part.

If someone more knowledgable than me has better solutions, pls enlighten us. The above workarounds are just that: they enable you to workaround the issue to get your project code up n running.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also did the same thing in the end, but I think it beat the purpose to only declare it one time in the deployment descriptor to put it as a header for each jsp files.

Comment: yep, like you say those workarounds do defeat the purpose somewhat. If I stumble on a proper solution sometime I'll provide that as well... I think it may be connected to needing to have the Maven dependency jars copied into e.g. the Apache's libraries... but that's just a guess.

Comment: Found a better workaround in this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998484/how-to-disable-the-jsp-validation-in-eclipse-helios   where user Abel ANEIROS says: Preferences > Validation > JSP Content Validator (uncheck manual & build)

Preferences > Validation > JSP Syntax Validator (uncheck manual & build)   " Since actually the Tomcat builds work ok despite the syntax complaints with Validation on, this seems ok to me... though I might want to toggle those Validation settings sometimes, to catch "real" errors.