# Spring MVC, how to include another controller/view inside a view (partialview)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I'm just starting out with Spring MVC having been trying to pickup Java(Web) for the few months.

I'm sure what I'm trying to achieve is very simply, but I can't find a solution that really works.

I'd like to include another controller/view inside a view. This could be a menu, or some other dynamically generated content. For example, let's say in a side bar of an application I need to display a list of categories. I don't want to have to retrieve these categories in every controller/view that needs to use them. I'd like to include another controller/view into the main page view so that this content can be placed in multiple views but managed by a single piece of code.

ASP.NET MVC has something called PartialViews, and most PHP frameworks seem to offer this kind of functionality, but I can't find anything like this in spring.

The closest I've come to resolving this issue is to use the jsp:include tag, which does work, infact it's almost the solution, but it generates errors in Eclipse because obviously Eclipse can't locate the path, as it's a spring RequestMapping i.e. /include/categories rather than a direct link to a physical file.

The other solution is to use Javascript to dynamically load content into the sidebar, but I don't want to do that.

Is there a 'correct' way to do this, or is there a way to supress the errors generated by eclipse for the jsp:include tag?

Comment: For validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998484/how-to-disable-the-jsp-validation-in-eclipse-helios

Answer (score 2):

If the content your are including is static and you don't have a lot of different pages, your approach with including jsps is ok. Otherewise, look at the templating frameworks like [Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) or [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at those. Is it bad practice to use jsp:include if it works? It seems to be displaying the dynamic content ok in my project.

Comment: It depends on how dynamic your content is and how complicated it makes the code. For a simple app it is fine...